# ggplot2 two data.frames, doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgdal, hmisc, r-maptools

I'm new to R and do not know how to plot two data.frames with ggplot2. I get the following error message: `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`

How can I put together my data with the underlying world map?

Here is my code:

```
require(Hmisc)
require(mapproj)
require(ggplot2)
require(rgdal)
require(maptools)
require(sp)
require(cshapes)
gpclibPermit()

world <- cshp(date=as.Date("2008-1-1"))
world.points <- fortify(world, region='COWCODE')
p <- ggplot(world.points, aes(long,lat,group=group)) + geom_polygon()

dat <- mdb.get("CLIWOC15_2000.mdb") # you can get the data from here: http://pendientedemigracion.ucm.es/info/cliwoc/cliwoc15.htm

tmp <- dat$CLIWOC15[,c("Lon3","Lat3")]

ggplot(world.points,aes(long,lat,group=group))
+geom_polygon()
+geom_point()
+geom_histogram(tmp,aes(Lon3,Lat3),alpha=0.01,size=1)
+coord_map()+ylim(-90,90)
```

Comment: basically, use `data = tmp` in your histogram layer, or put `tmp` second after `aes()`.

Answer (score 5):

If using multiple datasets, try pulling the `data` and `aes` info out of the `ggplot` 
function and putting it instead in each of the `geom_*` objects as needed.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=world.points,aes(long,lat,group=group)) +
  geom_point(data=world.points,aes(long,lat,group=group)) +

  # Separately, I'm not sure what the intended outcome is for this histogram, but it doesn't appear to be of a correct form 
  geom_histogram(data=tmp,aes(Lon3,Lat3),alpha=0.01,size=1) +
  coord_map() + 
  ylim(-90,90)
```

---

#### with regards to the arguments

Notice that while the first argument to the function `ggplot(.)` is `data`, this is not 
the case for most (any?) of the `geom_*`s.  Their first argument is the `mapping`.
Hence if the first argument you are using is a dataset, make sure to name it explicity,
ie `geom_point(data=myDataFrame, .)`

```
# You can always check the arguments by using the `args(.)` function

> args(ggplot)
function (data = NULL, ...) 
NULL

> args(geom_polygon)
function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", ...) 
NULL

> args(geom_histogram)
function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "bin", position = "stack", ...) 
NULL
```